# Gradient calculation in Hamming loss for multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, hamming-distance, multilabel-classification

I am doing a multilabel classification using some recurrent neural network structure. My question is about the loss function: my output will be vectors of true/false (1/0) values to indicate each label's class. Many resources said the Hamming loss is the appropriate objective. However, the Hamming loss has a problem in the gradient calculation:
**H = average (y_true XOR y_pred)**,the XOR cannot derive the gradient of the loss. So is there other loss functions for training multilabel classification? I've tried MSE and binary cross-entropy with individual sigmoid input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> H = average(y_true*(1-y_pred)+(1-y_true)*y_pred)

is a continuous approximation of the hamming loss.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your answering. In your approximation equation, I'm wondering if the y_true and y_pred are the probability or actual labels?

Comment: y_true is the actual labels, and y_pred is the probability.